# How to update WSO2 API Manager offline for open source user?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have API Manager V 4.0.0 installed on a linux server and for security reasons the server doesn't have an internet access, and according to the update document I must have an internet connection to update

https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/administer/updating-wso2-api-manager/

so how to update WSO2 API Manager offline to latest version for open-source user ?

Answer (score 0):

You can first do a create update where you have internet and then move the update to the isolated environment and then do an apply update. Take a look at [this](https://updates.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/updates/faq/#how-can-i-update-my-product-pack-if-my-environment-doesnt-have-internet-access).

Comment: thanks for the note, how to perform this update If I am an open source user, because I got an error: `Please note that you do not have an active subscription to access wso2am-4.0.0`

Comment: @MahmoudSaleh I'm afraid there is no easy way out if you don't have a subscription. Inorder to get the latest updates you will have to build the product from source. https://github.com/wso2/product-apim

Comment: Can't I get a trial subscription for 6 months for free ? as mentioned here : https://updates.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/updates/faq/#can-i-get-wso2-updates-free

Comment: @MahmoudSaleh I think you can get a trial subscription for evaluation purposes but AFAIK you can't run it in Production(Legal constraints). To get a trial subscription you may have to contact WSO2. For opensource users, the general guideline is to build from source.

Comment: can you please share the documentation link on how to update the apim by building from github source ?

Comment: @MahmoudSaleh Check this https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/reference/working-with-the-source-code/ Also there is nothing to update, once you build it will create anew api distribution(zip) with updates. So you can copy your configurations across to this new distribution.

Comment: is there's a guide or documentation for the files/folders that needs to be copied from old distribution to new distribution ?

Comment: @MahmoudSaleh Copy whatever you changed and the drivers, and point to the old DB.